# Is a closed set in $\ell^1$ closed in $\ell^2$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Prove or disprove that the set $S= \{x=(x_1,x_2,...)\in \ell^2 :\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}}x_i=1,x_i\geq0\}$ is a closed subset of $\ell^2$. Where $\ell^p$ is the sequence space equipped with the p- norm, $\|x\|_p=(\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}}|x_i|^p)^{1/p}$, for $1\leq p<\infty$.

I proved that $S$ is a closed subset of $\ell^1$. But I don't know wether a closed set in $\ell^1$ is closed in $\ell^2$ or not.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not closed in $l^{2}$. Consider the elements $(\frac 1 n,\frac 1 n,...,\frac 1 n,0,0,...)$ where $\frac 1 n$ is repeated $n$ times. These are elements of $S$ and they converge in $\ell^{2}$ norm to $(0,0,...)$ which is not in $S$.